# Error While OFFSET FETCH | SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pagination

I am trying to do pagination in SQL SERVER and I am getting two errors on OFFSET and ROWS

```
CREATE PROCEDURE XYZ
@offset int,
@limit int, 
@order char(4),
@Id int
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE ID = @id
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN @order = 'desc' THEN [TIME] END DESC,
CASE WHEN @order = 'asc' THEN [TIME] END ASC
*OFFSET* @offset FETCH ROWS NEXT @limit *ROWS* ONLY
END
GO
```

Error on `OFFSET`:

> Incorrect Syntax near 'OFFSET'.

Error on `ROWS`  (Second one):

> Incorrect Syntax near 'ROWS'. Expecting FROM.

Can someone help me out with this ?

Comment: `*OFFSET* @offset FETCH ROWS NEXT @limit *ROWS* ONLY` should be `OFFSET @offset ROWS FETCH NEXT @limit ROWS ONLY`

Comment: Are you definitely targeting SQL Server 2012 or later?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have used asterisk to identify the two keywords on which I am getting error.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Okay, I think where the problem is. I am using SQL Server 2008. :|

Comment: @siddharth Yes, but my comment is referring to the fact that `FETCH ROWS` should be `ROWS FETCH`...

Answer (score 1):

Well, in SQL Server 2008 you obviously can't use the `fetch...next` clause that was introduced in 2012.
However, this doesn't mean you can't do pagination.
One simple way is to use a cte with row_number:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,  -- Don't be lazy, specify the Columns list...
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (
                ORDER BY 
                CASE WHEN @order = 'desc' THEN [TIME] END DESC,
                CASE WHEN @order = 'asc' THEN [TIME] END ASC
            ) As rn 
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE ID = @id
)

SELECT * -- Don't be lazy, specify the Columns list...
FROM CTE
WHERE rn >= @offset
AND rn <= @offset + @limit
```